# SQL using GROUP BY and COUNT

Tags: sql, mariadb

I created the MariaDB(10.1.21) table named 'group_test' and saved some data as below.

```
Group  Item   Value1 Value2 Value3
A      a1     1      0      0
A      a2     1      1      1
A      a3     1      1      2
B      b1     1      1      0
B      b2     1      1      1
B      b3     1      0      0
B      b4     1      1      3
C      c1     1      1      0
C      c2     1      1      1
```

Using a query, I want to make the result as below at once.

```
Group  Items  Value1_1  Value2_1  Value3_1
A      3      3         2         1
B      4      4         3         1
C      2      2         2         1
```

Items means the total number of 'Item' in the 'Group'.
ValueN_1 means the total number of 'ValueN' value equal to 1 in the 'Group'.

I think I would use GROUP BY and COUNT but I don't know exactly what to do.
How do I write SQL to get the above results in one query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do a `GROUP BY`. Since Value1 to Value3 are only 0's and 1's, you can use `SUM()` to count the 1's.

```
select Group, count(Item), sum(Value1), sum(Value2), sum(Value3)
from tablename
group by Group
```

**Edit:** "*ValueN can have a value from 0 to 4*":

```
select Group,
       count(Item),
       sum(case when Value1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Value1_1,
       sum(case when Value2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Value2_1,
       sum(case when Value3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Value3_1
from tablename
group by Group
```

Comment: I really so sorry. ValueN can have a value from 0 to 4. I want to count value=1 only.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `value1`, `value2` and `value3` can only be either 0 or 1, you can write it like this

```
select  Group,
        count(*) as Items,
        sum(value1) as Value1_1,
        sum(value2) as Value2_1,
        sum(value3) as Value3_1
from    yourTable t1
group by Group
```

If that's not the case, you will have to use a `case` in the `sum`

```
select  Group,
        count(*) as Items,
        sum(case when value1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Value1_1,
        sum(case when value2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Value2_1,
        sum(case when value3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Value3_1
from    yourTable t1
group by Group
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY clause and SUM aggregate function in SELECT statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  SELECT [Group], count(Item) Item, sum(Value1) Value1, sum(Value2) Value2, 
       sum(Value3) Value3
  FROM Your_tableName
  GROUP BY [Group]
) A
```